# Energy spectral density vs power spectral density vs power spectral density per unit time

Tags: condensed-matter, signal-processing, noise

I recently started research to measure the voltage noise spectrum of materials to study their phase transitions. Before understanding physics, I am now confused by the three terms used in literature:

1. Energy spectral density (ESD)
2. Power spectral density (PSD)
3. Power spectral density per-unit-time (PSD per-unit-time)

I found the above terms ambiguous in different articles, and it seems like there are two different notations/definitions. I will call them **notation 1** and **notation 2** below. The fourier transform is well defined: let's say we have a continuous function in time domain $h(t)$, and after Fourier transform, we get $H(f)$.

$$
H(f) = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty} \int_{-T}^{T}h(t)e^{-i2{\pi}ft} dt \tag{1}
$$

### Notation 1

One set of notation I found in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_density) is as following: the EDS is defined as the modulus square of the Fourier transform, *i.e.*,
$$
ESD = |H(f)|^2 = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty}|\int_{-T}^{T}h(t)e^{-i2{\pi}ft} dt |^2
\tag{2}$$

and the power spectral density is defined as the time average of EDS

$$
PSD = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{2T}}|\int_{-T}^{T}h(t)e^{-i2{\pi}ft} dt |^2
\tag{3}$$

### Notation 2

Another set of notation I found in the book ***Numerical recipes*** by **William H. Press, etc** (https://e-maxx.ru/bookz/files/numerical_recipes.pdf) is different. In page 602, the (one-sided) power spectral density is defined in equation 12.0.15

$$
PSD = |H(f)|^2 + |H(-f)|^2
$$

and in page 603, the author mentioned the concept "power spectral density-per-unit-time", which, if I understand correctly, would be
$$
PSD-per-unit-time = {\frac{1}{2T}} PSD = \lim_{T \rightarrow \infty}{\frac{1}{2T}}(|\int_{-T}^{T}h(t)e^{-i2{\pi}ft} dt |^2 + |\int_{-T}^{T}h(t)e^{i2{\pi}ft} dt |^2)\tag{4}
$$

Now, **neglecting the difference between the one-sided and two-sided spectra**, it seems that **ESD in notation 1** = **PSD in notation 2**, and **PSD in notation 1** = **PSD-per-unit-time in notation 2**. If so, which notation is more commonly used in condensed matter physics? For example, I read in several condensed matter articles that for the Johnson-Nyquist noise of voltage of a resistor, the "power spectral density" equals $4k_{B}TR$ (here, $T$ is the temperature, not time). From dimension analysis, I guess in this context, the "power spectral density" is defined as in notation 1. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $h(t)$ to be a noise voltage wave and thus it has dimension $[V]$. Then in Eq.1 if measured over a $1\Omega$ unit resistance, the ESD as defined has dimension $\frac{[V^2][sec^2]}{\Omega}= \frac{J}{Hz}$ which is energy per unit bandwidth. This makes sense only oif $h$ is square integrable over all of $\infty <t < +\infty.$ If it is not square integrable but it has a finte power then, as in Eq.2, you divide this by $2T$ and get $\frac{Joule}{Hz\cdot sec} = \frac{Watt}{Hz}$ which is power density, that is power per unit bandwidth, as it should be.

I submit to you that the nomenclature "PSD per unit time" is total nonsense, even if it is used by Press, et al., because it is not power spectral density per unit time at all, but rather power spectral density. It might make sense to call energy density per unit time, but that would just be power density. Unfortunately, that is also nonsense because a stationary signal can *never* have a finite energy, it is not square integrable, and this is exactly the reason to use *power* density in the first place.

I would be astonished to learn that *this* nomenclature is used by anybody but a numerical analyst mathematician to whom the words, such as, energy, power, frequency, etc., may mean nothing.